# Custom variable 'layer' used before being initialized

Tags: ios, calayer, swift2

I would like to create a custom CALayer to set items corner radius.

```
func getLayerCorner(radius:CGFloat) -> CALayer
{
    let layer:CALayer
    layer.cornerRadius = radius
    layer.masksToBounds = true

    return layer
}
```

I'm getting `Variable 'layer' used before being initialized`

I'm still learning Swift and not sure how to init it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error exactly states what is wrong with your code. You need to initialise the layer before using:

```
func getLayerCorner(radius:CGFloat) -> CALayer
{
    let layer           = CALayer()
    layer.cornerRadius  = radius
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    return layer
}
```